# A value is printed in console.log, but not in css

Tags: css, next.js, import, constants

The constants MIN_Y, MAX_Y, and BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT were obtained from the file called constants.js. Since I am using Next.js, I got an error saying that I can't find the window if I don't apply the type of condition, so I wrote it like that.

However, when I clicked on the element in the developer tool, it said 'height: px'.

[image]

```
// constants.js

export const MIN_Y = 60;
export const MAX_Y = typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerHeight - 160;
export const BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT =
  typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerHeight - MIN_Y;
```

```
// BottomSheet.jsx

import { MIN_Y, BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT } from "../../common/config/constants";

export default function BottomSheet() {
  const { sheet, content } = useBottomSheet();

  console.log("bottom_sheet_height", BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT);
  return (
    <Wrapper
      ref={sheet}
    >
      <BottomSheetHeader />
      <div ref={content} className="overflow-touch">
        <Content />
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const Wrapper = styled(motion.div)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(100% - 90px); 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: ${MIN_Y}px;
  height: ${BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT && BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT}px;  // this 

  background: linear-gradient(
    359.26deg,
    #3c41c7 0.02%,
    #3742b2 83.23%,
    #3642ae 98.76%
  );
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

  transition: transform 650ms ease-out; 
`;
```

At first I wrote 'height: ${BOTTOM_SHEET_HEIGHT}px', but it didn't work, so I used the && operator.

But the result was the same.

I put MIN_Y in width, but MIN_Y comes out normally.

I checked if it's undefined from the time I loaded the constant, but it's not undefined in console.log.

[image]

I hope the height has the correct value. not 'height: px'